# C# Exceptions to Dictionary

Tags: c#, logging, exception

Is there any way (or library maybe) that can convert C# Exception (including SQL and Entity Framework) to a Dictionary that will include any specific data to the exception and also the InnerException ?

Comment: Exception class has a Data property dictionary? Not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is something you need to write on your own. Try something like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(Exception ex)
{
    var returnValue = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    returnValue.Add("Message", ex.Message);
    returnValue.Add("...", ex....);

    return returnValue;
}
```

But tjhere is no build-in function...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted. But serialize the Exception to json it much more better.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this Exception ex)
    {
        var exceptionData = ex.GetType()
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.Name != "InnerException")
               .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(ex, null));

        exceptionData.Add("Type", ex.GetType().ToString());

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            var innerExceptionData = ex.InnerException.ToDictionary();
            if ((exceptionData != null) && (innerExceptionData != null))
            {
                foreach (var keyPair in innerExceptionData)
                {
                    exceptionData.Add(string.Format("InnerException.{0}", keyPair.Key), keyPair.Value);
                }
            } 

        }

        return exceptionData;
    }
```